# How to reconnect jconsole on connection lost

Tags: java, load-testing, jconsole

I am doing load test for my project, when i tried to use jconsole to monitor when the server is restarted connection is getting lost is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jconsole connects to a process, when the server is restarted it gets a new process id, and jconsole did not know of the new process that is created. There is no other but you have to connect it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Jconsole is connected to a process (jvm). When your server is stop, the process doesn't exist anymore and so the jconsole connection is lost. And so you have to connect jconsole to the new process created when you server is starting.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any solution for this?

One way to ease the pain is to use a JMX URL instead of a process ID. The [JMX URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html) never changes on restart so while you have to reconnect anyway, at least the process is less painful.

URLs are of the format `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostName:portNum/jmxrmi`. Not sure what your server is, but [here's how to enable it on tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/monitoring.html#Enabling_JMX_Remote).